# css: width:fit-content & flex-wrap:wrap;

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm trying to figure out a way to use fit-content & flex-wrap:wrap on a container... here is what I'm getting :

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1.5px dashed #777;
  padding:.5rem;
  width:76%;
}

.box {
  padding:1rem;
  outline: 1px solid;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">testing, ok, fine</div>
    <div class="box">testing, ok, fine, ok, fine</div>
    <div class="box">testing, okokokok, fine</div>
    <div class="box">testingtestingtesting, ok, fine</div>
    <div class="box">testingtesting, ok, fine</div>
    <div class="box">testing, ok, finefinefinefine</div>
    <div class="box">testinfineg, ok, fine</div>
    <div class="box">testinffinefineineg, ok, fifinene</div>
  </div>
```

& here is what I want:
[image]

so how can I achieve that ?

Comment: try to change width to 67%

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Can't give an exact solution without knowing your code , but logic would be somewhat like this to achieve what you want

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class=item> Item </div>
   <div class=item> Item </div>
   <div class=item> Item </div>
   .......
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 75%;
}

.item {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```